# HTML: Can't get DIV to wrap tightly around inner divs

Tags: html, css

I've looked around StackOverflow for some solutions, and so far none of them are working. 
I'm trying to get my span to wrap tightly around its interior divs, but it always goes just a little bit wider than the divs inside. I've tried the different DISPLAY, FLOAT, MARGIN, and PADDING properties with no luck.

```
#column1, #column2, #column3
{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:33%;
  height:100vh;
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#weather_header
{
  width:70%;
  border: 5px outset skyblue;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
}

#weather_body
{
  width:70%;
  border: 5px inset skyblue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
}

#clock_header
{
  width:70%;
  border: 5px outset skyblue;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
}

#clock_body
{
  width:70%;
  border: 5px inset skyblue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
}

div.widget_box
{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.widget_header
{
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
  font-weight:bold;
}

div.widget_body
{
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {height:100vh;}
html {height:100vh;}
```

Basically the widget_box class holds the header and body classes. I just want the span's width to match the width of the div boxes (which will contain widgets of varying size).

Any help you could offer would be most appreciated!

Edit: HTML Code

```
<html>

<head>
 <title>Dashboard </title>

 <!--Importing JQuery into page-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

 <!--Importing Stylesheet into page-->
 <link type="text/css" href="dashboard_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

</head>

<body bgcolor = "white">

<div id="column1">

    <div class="widget_box">

        <div class="widget_header" id="weather_header">Weather</div>

        <div class="widget_body" id="weather_body">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netweather.accuweather.com/adcbin/netweather_v2/netweatherV2ex.asp?partner=netweather&tStyle=whteYell&logo=1&zipcode=73127&lang=eng&size=9&theme=blue&metric=0&target=_self"></script>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="widget_box">

        <div class="widget_header" id="clock_header">World Clock</div>

        <div class="widget_body" id="clock_body">

            <div align="center" style="margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;background:#000000;width:200px;padding:12px">

                <noscript>
                    <div align="center" style="width:140px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff ;color: #fff ;font-weight:bold">
                    <a style="padding:2px 1px;margin:2px 1px;font-size:12px;line-height:16px;font-family:arial;text-decoration:none;color:#000" href="http://localtimes.info">World Time </a>
                    </div>
                </noscript>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localtimes.info/world_clock.php?widget_number=11002&cp3_Hex=FF0000&cp2_Hex=000000&cp1_Hex=FFFFFF"></script>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div id="column2">Column 2</div>
<div id="column3">Column 3</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add your html...a js fiddle would be nice too

Comment: It's worth pointing out that a `<span>` element shouldn't wrap a `<div>` element. As you may know the first is an inline element, whereas the latter is a block element.

Comment: I'm not using any JS yet--just formatting the page. I tried using just DIVs originally, but that wasn't working and some people suggested using span for things like this. It's driving me crazy >_>

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  First, to answer your question, you're problem is here: `span.widget_box{margin:3px;}`

do this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/n6fpS/

```
span.widget_box{
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Second, as @danielepolencic said, its poorly structured to put divs inside of spans for the reasons he mentioned.

Is this what you're going for? http://jsfiddle.net/n6fpS/2/ If not, I think you should post another question and consider linking to an image representation or wire frame of your end goal.  It seems your asking a separate question now and that you're struggling with a fundamental understanding of CSS. I think it would benefit you to to spend an hour going through an online tutorial like this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/index.htm.  Also, I'd recommend inspecting your code with firebug or chrome developer tools (right click, inspect element) as it allows you to make changes in real time and see how things work.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code and got rid of the margin property and changed span to div, but it's not fixing the issue :-\ btw, I didn't know about that jsfiddle.net--that's pretty damn cool.

Comment: I was able to get the inner DIVs centered by making them float center instead of left, but I still have white space on either side of the widget boxes. Is there anyway to close that in a little bit?